# Everytime I weight paint it moves the model

Tags: mesh, bones, weight-painting

I am fairly new to blender. Please, if you know the answer just post it down here, and get it over with.

Whenever I weight paint the model I have it moves the painted area to some weird origin position.

Examples:
[image: See how here the bones are in the correct place.]

See how here the bones are in the correct place...

[image]
And then when I weight paint (it's not proper, just an example) it moves to some other position.

[image]
And then here is when I weight paint the entire thing. As you can see it gets moved to some other origin position. Notice how the bones are in the same place.

What's going on here and how could I fix it?

Comment: Why did you post the exact same question again?

Answer (score 0):

Your armature looks like it's set too low. If you lift it up a bit that may help with your problem. But also remember that weight painting is joining the bones to the mesh. They are meant to interact. It looks like you might have too many pieces of armature around the shoulders. I'm certainly no expert but I hope this helps.